# Entity Framework Core: Request for Composite Table (Composite Key)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

I. Hi! I create a composite key **ProjectSubProject** for my models: **Project** and **SubProject**. I have a problem with create GetAllProjects request, i want to get a

`IGrouping<Project, IEnumerable<SubProject>> or IDictionary` structure, but i get `IGrouping<Project, IEnumerable<GetAllProjectsViewModel>>`

Here is my request:

```
return _context.ProjectSubProjects
                .Include(ps => ps.Project)
                .Include(ps => ps.SubProject)
                .Select(ps => new GetAllProjectsViewModel
                {
                    Project = ps.Project,
                    SubProject = ps.SubProject,
                })
                .GroupBy(ps => ps.Project);
```

**Project.cs:**

```
public class Project
    {
        // PK
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string ProjectName { get; set; }

    }
```

**SubProject.cs:**

```
public class SubProject
    {
        // PK
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string SubProjectName { get; set; }
    }
```

**ProjectSubProject.cs**

```
public class ProjectSubProject
    {
        // PK
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        public Project Project { get; set; }

        // PK
        public int SubProjectId { get; set; }
        public SubProject SubProject { get; set; }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: because you are selecting `GetAllProjectsViewModel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get `IEnumerable<IGrouping<Project, IEnumerable<SubProject>>>` from your model, no `Include` or `Select` is needed. You can simply use the [`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549270(v=vs.110).aspx) method overload which allows you to pass element selector:

```
return _context.ProjectSubProjects
    .GroupBy(ps => ps.Project, ps => ps.SubProject);
```

**Update:** In order to include the project information in the Json representation, you could project the result to enumerable of some special or anonymous type having `Project` and `SubProjects` properties. Something like this:

```
return _context.ProjectSubProjects
    .GroupBy(ps => ps.Project, ps => ps.SubProject)
    .Select(g => new { Project = g.Key, SubProjects = g });
```

Comment: I need to `Include` this, because i return values in my app. This is WebApi method. And if i make as above i get `IGrouping<Project,Subproject>`

Comment: The `Include` makes no sense here (it doesn't matter what type of method is this). `Include` is used to load related data into entity. But you are not returning instances of `ProjectSubProject` entity at all, so there is no loading related data as well. The whole result is generated by the `GroupBy` query.

Comment: Yea, thanks i try to get values and all work fine. Thanks for description

Comment: But i have a one problem i get data but no info about project, only id and if i add ProjectName or something else GroupBy replace this by Id:

Comment: I Add picture in question

Comment: This seems to be related to Json serialization of grouping / dictionary structures.